# Best way of a Progressbar/Busyindicator while Rendering

Tags: c#, render, busyindicator

I need a Progressbar/Busyindicator while Rendering, because on the GUI are a lot of TextBoxes and different Controls. The DataGrid can't be virtualized because of dynamic Columns with CellTemplate Selector.

So i really need a Progressbar/Busyindicator so that the Application doesn't seem to be frozen.
My approach was to set a new Window in a STA-Thread when i know the GUI will render and close it after.
A Problem is, i can't set the Window-Owner. So if the application is not frozen (No Rendering, just a Task) the User can get the Window behind to the Foreground. Set the Window Topmost seems not to be a nice solution.

Any other Ideas of getting a Progressbar/Busyindicator while the Application is Rendering?

Code of my solution:

Thread starting/stopping Busywindow:

```
private void ShowBusyWindow(bool show)
    {
        if (show)
        {
            if (BusyThread == null || !BusyThread.IsAlive)
            {
                BusyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    // Create our context, and install it:
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

                    BusyWindow window = new BusyWindow();

                    // When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
                    window.Closed += (s, e) =>
                       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
                    window.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                    window.Show();
                    // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                }));
                BusyThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                // Make the thread a background thread
                BusyThread.IsBackground = true;

                BusyThread.Start();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (BusyThread != null && BusyThread.IsAlive)
                BusyThread.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Busywindow:

```
<Window x:Class="MEval.Wpf.View.BusyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="BusyWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"

    >
<Grid>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True">
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

Call Thread before and after Render-action:

```
    private DataTable _SelectedMeasurementData;
    public DataTable SelectedMeasurementData
    {
        get { return _SelectedMeasurementData; }
        set {

            if (value != null)
            {
                Messenger.Default.Send<BusyWindowMessage>(new BusyWindowMessage(true));
            }
            _SelectedMeasurementData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedMeasurementData");

            this.dispatcherProvider.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() =>
            {
                Messenger.Default.Send<BusyWindowMessage>(new BusyWindowMessage(false));
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is to not perform long-running computations on the UI thread. Put that logic in a different thread, and use some progress indication (e.g. `ProgressBar`) in the main UI thread. There are _lots_ of Q&A on StackOverflow, as well as details on the Internet, regarding specific techniques for this.

Comment: In my experience, when people say "long running computation" they actually mean I/O (unless they work in quantitative finance). Learn to use `async/await` (and stick to one thread) and you will have no problems at all.

Comment: This article is a great guide http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

Comment: @PeterDuniho /Aron: I really mean while Render-Progress. i perform the loading in Tasks, but the Application freezes a few seconds when it comes to Render a 30x100 Custom DataGrid as i described above

Comment: @PeterDuniho that is *not* the answer. OP specified that the *rendering* process was the one causing the app to freeze. Since rendering *must* be performed on the main UI thread, OP's desire to make a second UI thread to show a busy indicator makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Aron there are things like databinding or template / type matching that may take a second or two to compute. It's not much, but it's enough to make the app looks unresponsive and you can't have these things done in an async method.

Comment: @Chrono Ideally you do that. But you can't. Binding is a UI operation, which requires the UI thread, which blocks the UI thread. The only thing you can do is to fix your code to be performant.